# Ctrl+F functionality through a button in a html page in Angularjs 6

Tags: search, angular6

Ctrl+F functionality  through a button in a html page in Angularjs 6

I tried window.find(textToSearch) but it doesnt seem to work

I also tried importing windowRef object but it doesnt seem to work. Is there a proper solution to search for a text in angular 6 like the Ctrl+f feature in browser. Thant I can use on text box.

HTML Code:
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="{{ 'Search' | translate }}" (change) = "searchWord($event)">

TypeScript Code:
searchWord($event) {
Window.find($event.target.value); //Error: Property 'find' does not exist on type '{ new (): Window; prototype: Window; }'.
}

Comment: Can you try window instead Window.

Comment: Tried that it doesnt work